# I am trying to replace a particular string using .replace(). First and last searches are getting replaced but not second one

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to replace a particular string using .replace(). First and last searches are getting replaced but not second one.

```js
var text = "![alt text](https://www.reduceimages.com/img/image-after3.jpg) adadw  hjagwdjh ![alt text](https://www.reduceimages.com/img/image-after2.jpg)  akjhwdhawk ![alt text](https://www.reduceimages.com/img/image-afte1r.jpg)";

console.log("FInal Result --- > " + formatText(text));

function formatText(content) {
 const regex = /!\[(.*?)\]\((.*?)\)/g;

 let m;
 var printResult = (array) => {
  content = content.replace(array[0], "<img src='" + 123 + "'>");
  return false;
 };
 
 while ((m = regex.exec(content))) {
  
  if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
   regex.lastIndex++;
  }
  
  printResult(m);
  console.log("After Replace " + content + "\n");
 }

 return content;
}
```

Comment: `m.index`??? This approach makes no sense. If you're going to do a replace, just do it, it takes a RegExp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is: how to replace the text given with img tags with the captured url's as src. We need to capture some groups here:

I've changed the regex so the url is captured:

```
!\[[^\]]*\]      # match the ![alt text]. No need to capture this one.
\(
 (               # group 1 start
 [^)]*           # to capture the link
 )               # group 1 end
\)
```

What we're looking for is to replace the complete match  with an `img src=<group 1>`. Now look at the complete snippet:

```js
var text = "![alt text](https://www.reduceimages.com/img/image-after3.jpg) adadw  hjagwdjh ![alt text](https://www.reduceimages.com/img/image-after2.jpg)  akjhwdhawk ![alt text](https://www.reduceimages.com/img/image-afte1r.jpg)";

console.log("FInal Result --- > " + formatText(text));

function toImg(str, group1) {
   return "<img src=\'" + group1 + "'>";
}

function formatText(content) {
  const regex = /!\[[^\]]*\]\(([^)]*)\)/g;
  return content.replace(regex, toImg);
}
```

Comment: Thanks its working!!! But how will I get the url. Instead of 123 I want there image url.

Comment: I've adapted my answer. I think you should edit your question as well.

Comment: Do you actually need group 1 here, it doesn't seem to be used? JS will replace the whole match irrespective of any capture groups. It might also be simpler to use `return content.replace(regex, "<img src='$2'>");` (or `$1` as the case may be) instead of a replacement function.

Comment: There's no need to capture the complete match. The function toImg is obviously and intentionally syntactic sugar.